# A change of mind

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

In my language we have an expression which literally translated is “He was born a fireman but died in a fire” as a nice methaphor for a big shift in your way of thinking (like from conservative to reactionary). How would you say that in an elegant English?

By the way, the original expression in Italian is *Nacque pompiere ma morì da incendiario* (and you can say also the other way round).

Comment: Are you thinking of [this type of thing](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qui_gladio_ferit_gladio_perit)?

Comment: @tchrist - I don’t think so, the question is about an idiomatic expression that defines a radical change of mind.

Comment: The reason I ask is because the verb *bear* did not really make sense to me as you have used it in English. Then I thought of Virgil’s *Timeo Danaos et dona ferentes* and the Latin verb *fero* for *bear*. In case it might help, could you please give the original expression in your own language so that I may better understand it?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the question. I've edited to question to provide some more insights into it.

Comment: Thanks much, I do think it helps. *Born a sinner but died a saint* doesn’t seem too farfetched.

Comment: He changes his mindset, mentality or outlook. Or he had a metamorphosis, his was was reborn

Comment: Also, he had a change of heart.

Comment: Aha, incendiario is a fire; not incendiary. It's literally: born a firefighter but dies by fire. Born a saint but died a martyr? I think it means that you are born to do  one thing, and that thing ends up killing you. I do not think that means a radical shift in point of view.

Comment: If loyalties are at stake, we call them *turncoats*.

Comment: `a te che non ami i servi di partito// 
che ti chiedono il voto un voto pulito// 
partono tutti incendiari e fieri// 
ma quando arrivano sono tutti pompieri// a te che ascolti il mio disco forse sorridendo// 
giuro che la stessa rabbia sto vivendo// 
stiamo sulla stessa barca io e te// 
ti ti ti ti ti ti ti ti ti ti ti . . .`

Comment: This is from a [song](https://youtu.be/GF0Jju4E6xk?t=1m33s) written by Rino Gaetano in 1980 (‘Brigate Rosse’ era)  As far as I can make out, it's talking to the listener who mistrusts politicians, who are like the chickens in a yard pecking: "ti ti ti ti". They promise change and revolution (setting up fires) but when they come back they are all "holier than thou" (firemen/firefighters) boasting of their heroics.... the singer says we (the ordinary people) are all in the same boat, the listener might be smiling  to all this but the singer shares his same anger and frustrations ....

Comment: I've been looking for the meaning of "ti tit ti" and I could only find the comment on YouTube who suggested this interpretation, it sounds plausible enough, but I couldn't find any references to confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the expression :

**poacher turned gamekeeper.**

It is used in various contexts where someone changes from one position into the opposite, though often it is when someone assumes an authoritative position (the gamekeeper phase) who once was in the position which was subject to regulation (the poacher phase).

> 1.BRITISH
>   someone who now protects the interests they previously attacked.
>   "in the clearest case ever of poacher turned gamekeeper, the brewers are joining together in a crusade against alcohol abuse"

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=poacher+turned+gamekeeper&oq=poacher+turned+gamekeeper&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5742j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> University poacher turned gamekeeper sets sights on vice-chancellors’ pay

[The Guardian 10th October 2017](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2017/oct/10/university-vice-chancellors-pay-office-for-students-nicola-dandridge)

---

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poacher+turned+gamekeeper&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoacher%20turned%20gamekeeper%3B%2Cc0) shows stronger usage, BrE over AmE, and dates the saying from about 1900.

Comment: @FrancescoMarchioni Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

The examples people have given mean the opposite of what you want to say. I cannot think of an idiomatic phrase in English with that meaning in English. I would use a near-literal translation "a firefighter turned arsonist" in inverted commas and then explain just what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like these?

If You Are Not a Liberal at 25, You Have No Heart. If You Are Not a Conservative at 35 You Have No Brain

(from [Quote Investigator](https://www.google.com/amp/s/quoteinvestigator.com/2014/02/24/heart-head/amp/), which gives other examples)

Or another

He was a liberal until he got married and had kids, after which he was conservative.